# How to parse date with letters after date number

Tags: java, parsing, date

I know how to use SimpleDateFormat in Java. But what is the nicest way to parse all the dates which has some letters after day number? Like these: "25th May 2014", "3rd May 2014", "1st May 2014". You see how letters could be different? So I do not want to create separate formater for every number ending. Is the re a better way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert all of them to a common one using `replaceAll` then put that one in your single formatter string.

```
theDate = theDate.replaceAll("(?:(st|nd|rd|th))","xx");
if (theDate.contains("guxx"))   // Handle fixing "August" becoming "Auguxx"
    theDate = theDate.replace("guxx","gust");
```

This will change `1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th` to `1xx 2xx 3xx 4xx 5xx`.  Now you can use the static string 'xx' in your pattern.

Comment: What happens to Augu`st` with that regex? Does it become Auguxx? I guess the assumption is to split by spaces first and handle only the day in the date.

Comment: Good catch. That case is now handled with a less expensive `replace` if it happens.  Thanks @ThisClark.